# Wso2 SVN based Deployment Synchronization

Tags: svn, wso2, visualsvn-server, wso2-esb

Hello I have a problem with my SVN (using VisualSVN) synchronization, the log file output an error while committing the synchronization:

```
    ERROR - CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask Deployment synch
    ronization commit for tenant -1234 failed
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.DeploymentSy
    nchronizerException: Error while committing artifacts to the SVN repository
            at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchroniz
    erServiceImpl.commit(DeploymentSynchronizerServiceImpl.java:105)...

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.DeploymentSynchronizerExcepti
on: Error while committing artifacts to the SVN repository
...
Caused by: org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNClientException: org.tigris
.subversion.svnclientadapter.commandline.CmdLineException: java.io.IOException:
Cannot run program "svn": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is
too long
...
Caused by: org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.commandline.CmdLineException:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn": CreateProcess error=206, The file
name or extension is too long...
```

Would could it be? Do I need any addittional library in my \repository\components\lib?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- change the configuration of "**SvnUrlAppendTenantId**" to true:
- put svn **repositories** is CARBON_HOME/conf/components/lib

...no errors now, but they don't share configuration... I am confused